# why can't i localize in a google tango ADF (from area description to start-of-service i only get a INITIALIZING pose, but no VALID poses)

Tags: android-ndk, google-project-tango

in my android-ndk-app i reproduced configuration and pose callback similar to sample cpp_basic_examples/hello_area_description from https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c

i do config:

```
...
TangoConfig_setBool( config, "config_enable_learning_mode", true )
TangoConfig_setString( config, "config_load_area_description_UUID", ADFId.c_str() );
...
```

then i connect the callback to all 3 kinds of frame pairs:

```
...
TangoCoordinateFramePair pairs[3] = {
    {TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE,
     TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE},
    {TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,
     TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE},
    {TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION,
     TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE}
};
TangoService_connectOnPoseAvailable( 3, pairs, onPoseAvailable )
...
```

and in onPoseAvailable():

```
...
if ( pair.base == TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_AREA_DESCRIPTION )
{
    if ( pair.target == TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE )
    {
        LOGVI( "\nGOOGLE TANGO POSE ADF TO SOS (CORRECTION)");
        // we got a pose correction
        isRelocalized = (poseData->status_code == TANGO_POSE_VALID);
    }
    else if ( pair.target == TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE )
    {
        LOGVI( "\nGOOGLE TANGO POSE ADF TO DEVICE");
        // apply pose as relative to learned Area
    }
}
else if( pair.base == TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_START_OF_SERVICE )
{
    if ( pair.target == TANGO_COORDINATE_FRAME_DEVICE )
    {
        LOGVI( "\nGOOGLE TANGO POSE SOS TO DEVICE");
        // apply pose as relative to Start-Of-Service pose
    }
}
...
```

everything looks good in console output, all error return codes are TANGO_SUCCESS

but in console output i get "GOOGLE TANGO POSE ADF TO SOS (CORRECTION)" only once with poseData->status_code TANGO_POSE_INITIALIZING, but never with status TANGO_POSE_VALID.

the same adf localizes in google's "ADF Inspector" app in less than a second at the same position that i tested with my app.

note:
i created the ADF that fails to relocate in tango explorer. meanwhile i suspect an "access to adf from another app" issue, but didn't find a solution in the documentation. i did "android.intent.action.REQUEST_TANGO_PERMISSION" with "ADF_LOAD_SAVE_PERMISSION", but that doesn't seem to be enough to get the dialog that allows the user to allow loading an ADF from another app.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue if your application is in `AreaLearningMode = ON`.
Make sure the app is not in `LearningMode`.